# How to determine length efficiently of precision for large decimal number in informatica

Tags: sql, informatica

We have file coming from Source system with some column value as 418871907669537340000000000000.00233 and we need to load them in SQL Table with decimal datatype ( 38,9) i.e. precision can't be more than 29 chars long else will lead to failure.
We cannot use TO_INTEGER(input_value) as Integer just takes 10 digits else will fail.
We are using something : find position of decimal and using substring find length of precision part and if precision > 29 chars flag that record as Discarded which is costly approach file has million of rows and 100 decimal columns.

Answer (score 1):

If it's coming from source as a number (e.g. float), just compare it with `10^29`.

If it comes as a string, first use `TO_FLOAT()` as [described in docs](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5-1/transformation-language-reference/functions/to_float.html) and then do the comparison against `10^29`, same as above.